# setOnScrollListener with setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, list, listview

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

I have listView on fragment, custom adapter and I want to set 2 listeners on it, but when I added `setOnScrollListener`first listener doesn't work. What's wrong? and how can I fix it?

Comment: what exactly does not work? the onScrollListener or the onItemClickListener? How do you verify that they are not working? Can you reveal some more code/info

Comment: I tried to debug it, when I tap on item a 'onItemClick' method doesnt call at all

Comment: please help, i think the problem in overrided onClick method by OnScrollListener

Comment: I'll need some more info. Maybe you can share some more of the relevant portions of the code. OnScrollListener does not have onClick, so it cannot override it, if I understand correctly what you mean

Comment: i found solution, i just implement OnClickListener in adapter and OnScrollListener in activity this is work well, but why this listeners doesnt (setOnScrollListener and setOnItemClickListener) works together in activity i dont know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which seemed to be caused by a misplaced `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call. Removing this line fixed the problem, as it turned out I didn't need it anyway.