# setOnScrollListener of ListView interrupts setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onscrolllistener

It took me two(!) days to figure out my problem.
I have `ListView` with both `onItemClickListener` and `onScrollListner`. If I implement the `onScrollListner` then no `ItemClick` actions are fired.

I saw this problem here: [setOnScrollListener with setOnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678634/setonscrolllistener-with-setonitemclicklistener) and here:[Android: cannot set both: setOnItemClickListener setOnScrollListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959209/android-cannot-set-both-setonitemclicklistener-setonscrolllistener) with no real solution.

I have also noticed (in the emulator) that when one of the rows (in the `ListView`) is selected then `ItemClick` does fire (I assume that it works in not touch mode).

Very frustrating, can anyone think of a solution?

Some code:

## Custom ListView

```
public class CustomHomeListView extends ListView implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, OnScrollListener, IReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = CustomHomeListView.class.getSimpleName();

    private static Context mContext;
    List<DiscussionModel> mDiscussionsArray = new ArrayList<DiscussionModel>();

    private DiscussionsCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private boolean mIsLoading;
    private int mCurrentMinDiscussionRowIndex;
    private View mFooterView;
    private int mFirstVisiblePosition;
    private int mSelectedItemPosition;
    private int mDividerHeight;
    private int mSavedPositionInsideListView;

    public MyResultReceiver mReceiver;

    public void onCreate() {

        // for computing scroll position to an item after data fetch
        mDividerHeight = getDividerHeight();
        mSavedPositionInsideListView = 0;

        // prepare ResultReceiver for informing that puller service is done
        mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
        mReceiver.setReceiver(this);

        mCurrentMinDiscussionRowIndex = -1; // default value for retrieving most
        // recent
        // posts from web

        mAdapter = new DiscussionsCustomAdapter(mContext);
        CrowdietApplication cda = (CrowdietApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext();
        mAdapter.setCurrentUserUid(cda.getUserId());
        setAdapter(mAdapter);

        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mFooterView = ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.home_list_view_footer, null);

        //setCustomHomeListViewOnScrollListener();

        pullDiscussions();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        DiscussionModel discussion = mDiscussionsArray.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DiscussionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CONSTS_DISCUSSIONS.DISCUSSION_ID_FROM_CALLING_ACTIVITY, discussion.getDiscussionId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        mCurrentMinDiscussionRowIndex = -1;
        pullDiscussions();
    }

    private void pullDiscussions() {
        mIsLoading = true;

        // preparing puller service
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PullDiscussionsListIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(CONSTS_APP_SIGNALS.MIN_DISCUSSION_ROW_INDEX_TO_FETCH, mCurrentMinDiscussionRowIndex);
        intent.putExtra(CONSTS_APP_SIGNALS.RECEIVER_TAG, mReceiver);
        mContext.startService(intent);

    }

    private void refreshListFromDatabase() {
        DbDiscussions dbDiscussions = new DbDiscussions(mContext);
        Cursor discussionsCursor;

        discussionsCursor = dbDiscussions.getDiscussions();
        if (discussionsCursor != null && discussionsCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            prepareDiscussionsArray(discussionsCursor);
            mCurrentMinDiscussionRowIndex = dbDiscussions.getMinDiscussionRowIndex();
            mAdapter.setData(mDiscussionsArray);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mIsLoading = false;
        }
        discussionsCursor.close();
        dbDiscussions.destroy();
    }

    private void prepareDiscussionsArray(Cursor discussionsCursor) {
        mDiscussionsArray.clear();
        int noOfReturnedDiscussions = discussionsCursor.getCount();

        discussionsCursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfReturnedDiscussions; i++) {
            DiscussionModel discussion = new DiscussionModel();
            discussion.setDiscussionId(discussionsCursor.getString(discussionsCursor.getColumnIndex(CONSTS_DISCUSSIONS.FIELD_DISCUSSION_ID)));
            discussion.setDiscussionTitle(discussionsCursor.getString(discussionsCursor.getColumnIndex(CONSTS_DISCUSSIONS.FIELD_DISCUSSION_TITLE)));
            discussion.setUsername(discussionsCursor.getString(discussionsCursor.getColumnIndex(CONSTS_DISCUSSIONS.FIELD_USERNAME)));

            mDiscussionsArray.add(discussion);
            discussionsCursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }

    private int calcItemPosition() {
        int posInListView = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedItemPosition - mFirstVisiblePosition - 1; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child == null) {
                break;
            }
            posInListView += child.getHeight() + mDividerHeight;
        }
        // Log.d(TAG, "measured height :" + posInListView);
        return posInListView;
    }

    public CustomHomeListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    private void prepareForMySetSelection() {
        if (mSelectedItemPosition > -1) {
            mSavedPositionInsideListView = calcItemPosition();
        }
    }

    private void mySetSelection() {
        if (mSelectedItemPosition > -1) {
            setSelectionFromTop(mSelectedItemPosition, mSavedPositionInsideListView);
        } else {
            setSelection(mFirstVisiblePosition);
        }
    }

    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        prepareForMySetSelection(); // should be before
                                    // RefreshListFromDatabase() so that
                                    // actual position inside adapter is
                                    // saved
        refreshListFromDatabase();
        setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mySetSelection();
        // }
        removeFooterView(mFooterView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        mFirstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
        mSelectedItemPosition = getSelectedItemPosition();

        if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
            int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
            if (l >= totalItemCount && !mIsLoading) {
                addFooterView(mFooterView);
                pullDiscussions();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't imagine this doesn't work as I've used the combination of listeners in the past. Can you provide some of the code you're working with?

Comment: both listeners work without any problems, unless you are doing some tricky things...

Comment: I added some code. nothing tricky there, I think. I'm really clueless. Moreover, when I'm working with data set from local computer it works fine, when I work with (much samller) remote db the problem appears.

Comment: Well, I removed adding and removing the footer (which only displays progressView) and it works. Still, I can't figure out what's going on here.